# How to disable postback on click of a button in the Gridview?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, updatepanel

i am working on vb.net.
When i click a button in one of the row in the gridview, i am called a function to delete the data of tha row. it is working but it is getting postback.
i have placed gridview inside asp updatepanel.
How to prevent postback.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have made your UpdatePanel's UpdateMode="Conditional"? You can define [AsyncPostbackTriggers](http://AsyncPostbackTriggers) to f.e. your delete-button(eventname is optional and for button click is default).
To delete your row you have to delete it from the gridview's datasource and then rebind it to it.